# TypeScript: How to return conditional types in function with rest parameter?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I want to make a function with rest parameter which will return **conditional types** like this:

- **null** when provided *undefined value*
- **string** when provided *one number*
- **array of strings** when provided *multiple numbers*

I was trying to write this function in multiple forms using TypeScript **extends** syntax but unfortunately none of these was working.

I was also trying to write function where first parameter was a number and the second one was rest parameter but it also didn't work.

This is how working code looks right now **except of** proper conditional return of types:

```js
import { rem } from "polished";

type UnitValue = number | undefined;

const unit = (...values: UnitValue[]): string | string[] | null => {
  const result: string[] = [];

  values.forEach(value => {
    if (value) {
      result.push(rem(value));
    }
  });

  if (result.length === 1) {
    return result[0];
  }

  if (result.length > 1) {
    return result;
  }

  return null;
};
```

Recreated case in *codesansbox.io* -> [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-currying-sdcb6?fontsize=14)

I need this function to return **exactly and only** these types in those three cases:

- `unit(undefined) -> null`
- `unit(16) -> string`
- `unit(16, 32) -> string[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by using [function overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).
Your code will look like this:

```
import { rem } from "polished";

function unit(...values: undefined[]): null;
function unit(...values: [number]): string;
function unit(...values: number[]): string[];
function unit(...values): null | string | string[] {
  const result: string[] = [];

  values.forEach(value => {
    if (value) {
      result.push(rem(value));
    }
  });

  if (result.length === 1) {
    return result[0];
  }

  if (result.length > 1) {
    return result;
  }

  return null;
}
```

You can check out in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Afunction%20unit(...values%3A%20undefined[])%3A%20null%3B%0D%0Afunction%20unit(...values%3A%20[number])%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Afunction%20unit(...values%3A%20number[])%3A%20string[]%3B%0D%0Afunction%20unit(...values)%3A%20null%20%7C%20string%20%7C%20string[]%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%3A%20string[]%20%3D%20[]%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20values.forEach(value%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.push(rem(value))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(result.length%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result[0]%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(result.length%20%3E%201)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test1%20%3D%20unit()%20%2F%2F%20Hover%20%22test1%22%20%3D%20null%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20unit(10)%20%2F%2F%20Hover%20%22test2%22%20%3D%20string%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20unit(10%2C%2020)%20%2F%2F%20Hover%20%22test3%22%20%3D%20string[]).